# Flutter Firestore PlatformException

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to retrieve data from firestore database.
But there's an exception throwing to me saying:

### PlatformException
code: 'null-error'
message: 'Host platform returned null value for non-null return value.

Here's my **main.dart**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: const Screen1(),      
    ),
  );
}
```

And here's my **screen_1.dart**

```
class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Screen1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Screen1> createState() => _Screen1State();
}

class _Screen1State extends State<Screen1> {
  List<String> student = [];

  Future getStudent() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('student_Info').get().then(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach(
            (document) {                  
              print(document.reference);
            },
          ),
        );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getStudent();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

At first I called `flutterfire configure` in terminal and select a project. Then I created collection. And also I changed **minsdkversion** to **21** in *\android\app\build.gradle*. What's wrong with my code???

Appreciate if someone can advise. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've configure flutterfire cli well then all you have to do is import and use it in the options like this:

```
...
import 'firebase_options.dart';

...
void main(){
...
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to run `flutterfire configure` in the terminal, it will automatically generate the `firebase_options.dart` file. Then you can try the following code:

```
import 'firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: const Screen1(),      
    ),
  );
}
```